# How to get a cgitb traceback inside a try/except block?

Tags: python, exception, cgitb

[Usually](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgitb.html) it is advised to initialize *cgitb* at the beginning of a script with the function `cgitb.enable()`.

But how can I do to use cgitb to format a special exception I catched in a try/except block, without registering cgitb as a global exception handler?

I suppose it would look like this:

```
import cgitb
try:
    1/0
except Exception as exc:
    print(cgitb.something(exc))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cgitb
import sys
try:
    1/0
except Exception:
    print(cgitb.text(sys.exc_info()))
```